# Problem with second distributional derivative

Tags: mathematical-physics, distribution-theory

I have the following function:
 $ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x},  & \text{if $x>0$} \\
\sqrt[3]{|x|}, & \text{if $x<0$ }
\end{cases}
$.

I have to find $f'(x)$, $f''(x)$ as distributions.
With $f'(x)$ it is quite simple:
$ f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},  & \text{if $x>0$} \\
-\frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{|x|}}, & \text{if $x<0$ }
\end{cases}
$, and there is no problem here as it defines a regular function, since both roots are summable at $0$.
I am having trouble in finding $f''(x)$ as $f'(x)$ has some kind of infinite discontinuity, and i don't know how to deal with them. If it was a jump discontinuity, there wouldn't be a problem: we would just get delta function at $0$.

Comment: Your $f'$ should be $-\frac 13 |x|^{-2/3}$ for $x<0$. I'd try to show that the second derivative has some form of *principal value*.

Answer (score 0):

You can just differentiate both parts again to get:

$$ f''(x) =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{4x\sqrt{x}},  & \text{if $x>0$} \\
-\frac{2}{9\sqrt[3]{x^2}|x|}, & \text{if $x<0$ }
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: No, the thing is that i have to find $f''(x)$ as an element of $\operatorname{D}'{(\mathbb{R})}$. And this function does not define a regular linear functional since it is not in $L_1^{loc}(\mathbb{R})$.